# Is iostat unreliable?

Tags: iostat

I have noticed something worrying with iostat that I can't quite explain - it appears iostat may not be quite reliable(?)

I'm trying to troubleshoot poor MySQL performance, and one ovious place to look is the disks, so:

```
ip-10-14-4-14 root : iostat -x nvme2n1
Linux 5.4.0-1029-aws (ip-10-14-4-14)    10/27/21        _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.19    0.00    0.47    0.84    0.00   97.49

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
nvme2n1          4.93    160.70     0.26   4.95    0.53    32.60  216.03   6863.39    57.07  20.90    0.78    31.77    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00  16.50
```

That doesn't look too bad - `%util` is only 16.5; however:

```
ip-10-14-4-14 root : iostat -y 1 -x nvme2n1
Linux 5.4.0-1029-aws (ip-10-14-4-14)    10/27/21        _x86_64_        (8 CPU)


avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           4.65    0.00    1.26    1.13    0.00   92.96

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
nvme2n1         10.00    160.00     0.00   0.00    0.40    16.00 2058.00  40260.00   326.00  13.67    0.65    19.56    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00 100.00
```

Same system, almost at the same time, but now `%util` is 100. I've even tried running the first version in a loop, and then `%util` stays low:

```
for i in $(seq 1 50); do iostat -x nvme2n1; done
Linux 5.4.0-1029-aws (ip-10-14-4-14)    10/27/21        _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.19    0.00    0.48    0.84    0.00   97.49

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
nvme2n1          4.93    160.70     0.26   4.95    0.53    32.59  216.32   6868.15    57.10  20.88    0.78    31.75    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00  16.51
...
```

What's going on - am I just not using the tool correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out: the option `-y` throws out the first set of results, which isn't realiable, and waits for iostat to do a full sampling.

IOW, always use `iostat -y` - or try `sar -d -p 1 1`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).